# ionSlides is undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-slides

I have a basic slider in my Ionic 4 project but this.slides is undefined at every point. A few days ago this worked, I just can't figure out why it doesn't work now.

TS-File:

```
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

export class xyPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(IonSlides, { static: true }) slides: IonSlides;

  constructor() {}


  public getSlideIndex() {
    console.log(this.slides);
    this.slides.getActiveIndex().then((index: number) => {
        this.currentSlideIndex = index;
     });
  }
}
```

Template:

```html
<ion-slides 
    options="slideOpts" 
    pager="true"
    (ionSlideDidChange)="getSlideIndex()">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of SlideOptions | keyvalue">
          <div class="slide-image img3 animated fadeIn">
            ...
          </div>
        </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Error:

```
ERROR Error: 
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getActiveIndex' of undefined
```

The next and previous buttons with "this.slides.slideNext();" have the same error.

Comment: Is IonSlides in your providers?

Comment: it's not, but even if I add it, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a trivial problem caused by me.
Thanks to all those who wanted to help me!

I had an *ngIf="" on the parent element of the slider, that blocked it.

It was probably too obvious to see right away.